# Java Calendar DST advance issue/bug

Tags: java, calendar, dst

If I have a date of 2015-03-07 02:00:00 -0500 and I add 1 day to it (Time changes from 2 -> 3 on march 8) I get the wrong value back as the resulting Calendar:

**Before Adding 1 Day: 2015-03-07 02:00:00 -0500**

**After Adding 1 Day: 2015-03-08 01:00:00 -0500**

The day was adjusted by performing the following line of code:

```
        System.out.println("Before Adding 1 Day: " + getFormattedDate(cal));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        System.out.println("After Adding 1 Day: " + getFormattedDate(cal));
```

How does the Calender end up with a 1am time when 2am moves forward to 3am.

Well it should behave the same as if you added 1 day to the same time Calendar in UTC and converted it back which always returns 3am as expected since 2am has really become 3am. Using the GMT based calendar for the same time produces:

**Before Adding 1 Day cal: 2015-03-07 02:00:00 -0500**

**Before Adding 1 Day GMT cal: 2015-03-07 07:00:00 +0000**

**After Adding 1 Day GMT cal: 2015-03-08 07:00:00 +0000**

**After Adding 1 Day cal : 2015-03-08 03:00:00 -0400**

```
        Calendar gmtCal = Calendar.getInstance(UTC_TIMEZONE);
        gmtCal.setTimeInMillis(calTime);
        System.out.println("Before Adding 1 Day cal: " + getFormattedDate(cal));
        System.out.println("Before Adding 1 Day GMT cal: " + getFormattedDate(gmtCal));
        gmtCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(gmtCal.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("After Adding 1 Day GMT cal: " + getFormattedDate(gmtCal));
        System.out.println("After Adding 1 Day cal : " + getFormattedDate(cal));
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the setting for your time zone.

Comment: You've added some code, but you need to show a definition for `getFormattedDate` and `calTime`. You also haven't shown us `cal`. Your example code should compile cleanly and demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those timezones implementing DST, the local time `2015-03-07 02:00:00 -0500` technically doesn't exist. In those cases, I would guess the results are undefined. To be sure, you can test with `2015-03-07 01:59:59 -0500` and `2015-03-07 03:00:00 -0500` which should give correct results, or at least not convoluted with DST transition.

But losing an hour would make sense in this case if, for example, the code internally is adding 86400 seconds.

Comment: Well it should behave the same as if you added 1 day to the same time Calendar in UTC and converted it back which always returns 3am as expected since 2am has really become 3am.